# How to ignore duplicate field values while inserting duplicates in Mongodb with Java syntax

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am able to insert the documents in mongodb collection but but it is inserting the duplicate values in collection .How to avoid the duplicates field value ("System.UniqueNumber") in  java :Document looks like below .I need check the System.UniqueNumber value ,in case if any value is existing ,document should not be inserted to database. I tried with upsert oepration but it is not happening . Can anyone help how to ignore the duplicates in java .

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("abedfg"), 
    "Amoun" : {
        "Type" : {
            "key" : "dollar", 
            "value" : "system"
        }, 
"System" : {
 
        "UniqueNumber" : "123", 
        "color" : "Red", 
    }, 


    public boolean create(@Valid @RequestBody Document... documents) {
        MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase("Database");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Database");

        List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<>(bookings.length);
        for (Document doc: documents) {
            documentList.add(Document.parse(booking.toJson()));
        }
        collection.insertMany(documentList);
       
    }
```

Comment: If you want to enforce uniqueness, then you should create a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) on the `'System.UniqueNumber'` field

Comment: Use unique index to field that may prevent duplicate value from insert or upsert